# Excel VBA back button that goes to previous tab

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a back button to put on every tab in my excel project that once pressed will bring you to the previous tab that I last accessed.  For example if I am in the sheet3 tab and then I move to the Sheet8 tab, I want to be able to click the back button in sheet8 to bring me back to that sheet3 tab.  So basically Excel is keeping track of my previous visit to whatever tab I was last at and bringing me back to it when I press the back button.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: cool concept though :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to track the last tab accessed to pull this off.

To capture the sheet when you switch tabs you can make use of the workbook's `SheetDeactivate()` event. In VBE, click into "ThisWorkbook" in your VBAProject and add the following code:

[image]

```
'Global Variable to hold last sheet selected
Public lastSheet As Object

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    'When we deactivate a tab toss the deactivated sheet into the lastSheet global
    Set lastSheet = Sh
End Sub
```

Now, when we want to access the last sheet clicked, we can refer to variable `lastSheet`.

In a new module add the following subroutine:

[image]

```
Sub goBack()
    'go back to the last sheet using the lastSheet variable
    ThisWorkbook.lastSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Now you can add buttons (or shapes) to your tabs and point them to the `GoBack()` subroutine.